# How to add a button into a textblock in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, controls, uwp-xaml

I want to add a `Button` in a `Textblock`. I mean, Buttons(Objects) among Text.

The code below does not work.

```
<TextBlock>
  <Button />
</TextBlock>
```

`TextBlock` seems to support only text, so which control should I use?

Comment: In short, I'm afraid you can't. It doesn't make any sense though. A textblock contains only text. You should use a container for this purpose.

Comment: What do u want to achieve? Adding a button among a paragraph of text?

Answer (score 3):

You can't display anything but text in a `TextBlock`. If you want to display a `Button` in some running text you could for example use a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Some text with a " /><Button Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Center" /><TextBlock Text="in it." />
</StackPanel>
```